# How to properly use -webkit-device-pixel-ratio on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, mobile, css, mobile-safari

`-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` query is supported by both iOS and Android but since iOS does not support `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` it leads to different results. For example:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    body { font-size: 2em; }
}
```

will make font look good on Galaxy Nexus, but on iPhone 4 it will be too big.

Is there a way to emulate `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` on iOS without JavaScript or to disable `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` on iOS and leave its users with blurry images as a fallback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), /* Retina on Webkit */
       (min-resolution: 192dpi)             /* Everyone else */ {
...
}
```

from this great article I incidentally read today:
http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/